# Reducing the initial size of the transaction log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have a database (in production) where the initial size of the database was set inappropriately large (28GB). If I right click on the database in SQL Server management studio and attempt to shrink the LDF file I see that the file is 99% free space. So essentially over 27GB of disk space is being unnecessarily used.

However if I run the shrink either from the GUI or using SQL statements, it won't shrink below the initial size. I've tried changing the initial size both using SQL statements and the GUI but it won't change. It acts like it does but nothing happens.

How the heck can I get the initial size reduced to 500MB so that I can shrink the file and free up that 27GB of disk space.

Thanks
Brad

Comment: @Reaces: They *are* the same if you consider the case where someone created a db with a 28Gb log file. The total size of the database is the sum of the sizes of all the files involved.

Comment: @Brad: I don't think it is possible to shrink the log past its original size. Also unfortunately, you can't get rid of the initial log file, afaik. I'll be interested to see if someone else has a solution for you!

Comment: @BenThul Apparently my first comment went without a link [so here it is](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35182/manually-set-log-file-size-after-shrink-sql-server-2008-r2). Shrinking the log file is done with a DBCC action and switching the database from full to simple recovery and back again. You can change the initial size by using the `ALTER DATABASE` and `MODIFY FILE` commands.

Comment: @Reaces: I've shrunk many a log file. And I've run into this exact problem. But, I did just try a test and learned something. Specifically, I created a test db with a 100 Mb log and then tried to shrink it down. It let me shrink it some, but complained that you can't have fewer than two VLFs in the log file. So, if the OPs database was created with an initial log file of 28 Gb, s/he should be able to shrink it down to 14 Gb (since IIRC it breaks the log into four VLFs initially).

Comment: @BenThul Actually the amount of initial VLF files is dependent on the first growth of the log file. So if it was indeed set at a size of 28Gb from the start it would have 16 VLF's. I'm not entirely sure where I learned this but I found a corroborating reference pretty fast [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/transaction-log-vlfs-too-many-or-too-few/).

Comment: @BenThul running the following: ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] 
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;

CHECKPOINT;

DBCC SHRINKFILE (MyDB_log,0);

ALTER DATABASE [MyDB]
MODIFY FILE (NAME=MyDB_log,SIZE=500MB,MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED,FILEGROWTH=100MB);

--Optional if you want the database in full recovery mode 
--for point in time recovery going forward
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] 
SET RECOVERY FULL;

Comment: I get the following error: Cannot shrink log file 2 (MyDB_Log) because all logical log files are in use.

(1 row(s) affected)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
Msg 5039, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
MODIFY FILE failed. Specified size is less than current size.